# Booting to either setup or "all boot options tried" (samsung laptop)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, boot, reinstall

I had Windows 10 on a Samsung series 5 ultra laptop (came with 8.1, but I've upgraded it to 10). I decided to give the laptop away and instead of uninstalling all programs and deleting files I decided that reinstalling the whole OS would be easier and so created a bootable USB with https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 (second option).

In order to get the booting from USB going I had to change the bios:

- disabled fast bios mode and secure boot
- changed OS mode selection to "UEFI and CSM OS" (The options are 1)UEFI OS, 2) CSM OS, 3) UEFI and CSM OS)
- modified boot order so that the usb would be first

In the setup I first deleted all partitions and then created a single new one and continued. When it was complete it restarted. After the restart the setup started again. I figured it's because of the boot order, closed the setup, restarted and changed the boot order so that the ssd would be first, saved and restarted. And now "All boot options are tried. Press  key to recover with factory image using Recovery or another keys for next boot loop iteration" happened.

So I tried (meddling with boot order and doing the setup again) and failed a couple of times more, then decided to try installing windows 7 instead because I've done that previously many times. I used the ISO file I've always used and succeeded so far but the result was the same.

So my situtation at the moment is:

- I have windows 7 bootable flash drive
- the laptop has completed the
  windows 7 setup (may as well be windows 10 as it had exactly the same
  result)
- when I have the flash drive inserted, the setup begins after
  restart
- when I don't have the flash drive inserted, "All boot options
  are tried. Press  key to recover with factory image using
  Recovery or another keys for next boot loop iteration" happens

**What might cause this situation and what are my options at the moment?**

I'm considering creating a recovery image in my main PC (win10) and do the F4 recovery in the laptop. Is it a thinkable option?

In the hindsight I see that there is a "reset" option in windows 10 which I should have used. But it's too late now.

**Edit:**
[picture of BIOS boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TRc7.jpg)

Comment: maybe there's a good way you can look at what your current partitions are, and which are active.  But i'm not sure  off hand of a good free partition program that you can boot up and use to look at that. Gparted isn't very good(e.g. limited options re converting between partition types primary/extended/logical), but gparted should be enough to do what i'm speaking of.

Comment: also when you say you deleted all partitions, it's worth paying attention to what partitions your partition deleting program(windows setup?) showed you that you had, and whether that was what you expected. I'm not quite sure whether windows setup will always see any kind of partition, though maybe it will.  I know for example if I was looking to delete all partitions where win7 was installed, then one partition i'd look for is a 100MB partition in the before.. so after, it shouldn't be there. And if that partition wasn't shown then i'd know it hasn't deleted all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up when you changed this setting:

> changed OS mode selection to "UEFI and CSM OS"

Change it to "UEFI only" or something of that sort. You do not want CSM OS at all.

Prepare the flash drive by formatting it as FAT32, then drag and drop all files from the ISO to the flash drive. Nothing more must be done to the flash drive.

During or before you boot to setup wipe the disk.

During setup let Windows automatically partition the disk.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!
The options are 1)UEFI OS, 2) CSM OS, 3) UEFI and CSM OS.
When I change it to 1) it gives me the "all boot options tried" screen and when I press a key a 3-option box pops up. Doesn't matter which one I choose from there, it pops up again.

I can boot to setup only when 2) CSM OS or 3) UEFI and CSM OS is selected.
I'll update my question with this information and provide some pictures.